# QtCreator + cygwin + Boost: is debugging possible

Tags: c++, boost, cygwin, qt-creator

I'm trying to use QtCreator as an IDE for Windows platform. So far I have managed to create a "kit" that uses cygwin's gcc compiler, and to build a non-qt "hello world" project.  When I try to debug the project, I get

> "The debugger could not load the debugging helper library."

error and can see only assembler code. I have installed QtCreator as a standalone application, so I don't have either qt lib or mingw. If anybody knows how to make QtCreator debug projects using cygwin's gdb, I would really appreciate it.

P.S: The reason why I want to use QtCreator as an IDE is that Eclipse's indexer fails on parsing boost sources, it eats up way too much memory and I have to turn it off to make the IDE operable. And neither autocomplete or navigation of the class hierarchy works without the indexer.

Comment: Give NetBeans a try too. It is far more decent IDE for C++ than Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks for reply! I thought NetBeans is a java-only IDE. Does it support debugging?

Comment: Certainly it does support debugging with gcc/gdb. See http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/cnd/debugging.html

Comment: Yes, I have just installed and tested: it supports debugging and can handle boost sources. It fails to parse some template classes (shows false errors), but autocomplete still works. A good alternative to Eclipse CDT. Thanks!